# What's wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

What is wrong with this code? I am using jQuery.

```
function setPreviewUrl() {
        $post_title = $("#post_title").val();
        $post_content = $("#post_content").val();
        $.get('ajax/base64encode.php?name='+post_title, function(data1) {
            var $postTitle  =   null;
            $postTitle  =   data1;
        });
        $.get('ajax/base64encode.php?name='+post_content, function(data2) {
            var $postCont   =   null;
            $postCont   =   data2;
        });
        var $urlExten   =   null;
        $urlExten   =   '?post_title='+postTitle+'&post_cont='+postCont;
        $("a[href*='#change']").attr('href', '<?php echo $site_url; ?>admin/ajax/preview.php'+urlExten);
        $("#preview_frame").prop("href", '<?php echo $site_url; ?>admin/ajax/preview.php'+urlExten);
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do, and what happens when you run it?

Comment: Perhaps you should write what you want to achieve

Comment: please tell us what's wrong with this code! errors? different result than excpected?

Comment: In line $urlExten   =   '?post_title='+postTitle+'&post_cont='+postCont; you are using postTitle and postCont which are undefined in this scope, they are defined in that local function scope

Comment: @interjay - i expect it to change the url of a link with id=preview_frame....so that when i click on it....it shows an iframe of the changed link....

Comment: @NitinMidha - you seem to be right...i'll try it out...

Comment: `function setPreviewUrl() {
 $.get('ajax/base64encode.php?name=' + $("#post_title").val(), function(postTitle) {
  $.get('ajax/base64encode.php?name=' + $("#post_content").val(), function(postCont) {
   var urlExten = '?post_title=' + postTitle + '&post_cont=' + postCont;
   $("a[href*='#change']").attr('href', '<?php echo $site_url; ?>admin/ajax/preview.php' + urlExten);
   $("#preview_frame").prop('href', '<?php echo $site_url; ?>admin/ajax/preview.php' + urlExten);
  });
 });
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're messing up with asynchronous code:

```
function setPreviewUrl() {
        var $post_title = null; 
        $post_title = $("#post_title").val();
        var $post_content = null; 
        $post_content = $("#post_content").val();
        $.get('ajax/base64encode.php?name='+post_title, function(data1) {
            var $postTitle  =   null;
            $postTitle  =   data1;
        });
        $.get('ajax/base64encode.php?name='+post_content, function(data2) {
            var $postCont   =   null;
            $postCont   =   data2;
        });
        // Those functions above will execute when the get is done, in the
        // meantime the code below is executed, so the variables have not been
        // set yet.
        // Also, the variables are only declared inside the get function so they
        // are not accessible due to their scope.
        var $urlExten   =   null;
        $urlExten   =   '?post_title='+postTitle+'&post_cont='+postCont;
        $("a[href*='#change']").attr('href', '<?php echo $site_url; ?>admin/ajax/preview.php'+urlExten);
        $("#preview_frame").prop("href", '<?php echo $site_url; ?>admin/ajax/preview.php'+urlExten);
    }
```